# How to handle a cross-site duplicate that really should be here?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/what-list-of-words-do-you-use-when-creating-a-language) is one that is very important for conlang creation, and thus in my view absolutely belongs on [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com). However, [it has also been asked and answered on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/word-lists-for-constructed-languages). I’ve posted a comment to the question here pointing to the Worldbuilding question; should I (or anyone else) copy that answer, possibly including other resources, to this question?

Comment: That world-building question was asked before the conlang site was opened. It can be asked again here—and I see, it has a local duplicate already.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica - yeah, I was alerted to the "canonical vocabulary question" earlier, thus the acceptance of CuriousDannii's answer. In the absense of the CVQ, though, I certainly believe that the question should have "stood" here; the question in my mind was whether the pointer to the Worldbuilding question was appropriate and sufficient, or whether the WB answer should more properly have been copied here (with credit/attribution, plus any additional information that may have been developed in the interim).

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica - based on the accepted answer, I now believe that should a similar situation without a local duplicate arise, the correct course of action would be to copy the answer with credit/attribution/additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to close it as a duplicate of our canonical vocabulary question. If you think there's anything missing from the WB Q&A feel free to adapt it (with proper attribution) in an answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Yeah, OK, somehow I never knew about _that_ question. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since the particular question was asked on Worldbuilding before Constructed Languages was founded, I think that was handled well enough.

**Going forward...**

As a member of both forums (and a moderator of neither), what I would do, and have done in the past couple years, is flag the WB query for migration to here. Invented languages are of course on topic at WB for valid reasons, but they may be even more on topic here.

What I do is consider how much *weight* the OP is placing on the glossopoetics vs the geopoetics of the question.  For example, if someone asked **What Kinds of Linguistic Sounds Can an Intelligent / Sapient Hippogriff Pronounce**, I'd consider the weight there to be more towards worldbuilding, as it's a question of physiology and anatomy more than anything else.  If the question were **Okay, I Know What Kinds of Sounds a Hippogriff Can Make: What Strategies Can I Employ in Determining Which Sounds Might Be Used Linguistically**, I'd say that's right up Constructed Language's alley, and I would suggest a migration of that one.

Now, we've fielded questions like the first one here in CL before (there was one about a lipless humanoid a while back). If the first Hippogriff query were asked here, I wouldn't suggest migrating to WB unless the OP were really interested in the details of anatomy rather than language.

If the OP asked these two queries in both forums, I'd VTC the first query here in CL and VTC the other query in WB. Reason being, both have duplicates in better forums. It's a matter of keeping the question in the more appropriate place. An edit to the effect that there is a duplicate at CL within the body of the closed query on WB, if the question got any answers, would be a good idea.

Comment: I think your way of distinguishing the sites is helpful.